# Display template - Managed properties column display name

Tags: display-template, managed-property

I'm creating a custom display template, where I want to show the metadata field name and it's value.

The problem is that the Managed Properties use the internal name, and not the display name. How can I get the display name from the internal name?

For the code below: it's in a loop, so the `i` is the index of the loop.

```
var property = $getItemValue(ctx, String.format("Property {0}", i));
console.log(property.managedPropertyName) //This is the internal name.
```

[image]